# Login SQL from another domain

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, visual-studio

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 on a separate domain to Visual Studio/ my computer. (It’s my personal machine on a workgroup).

I have access to the server and can log in fine with SQL authentication but want to log on via Windows Authentication. When I try I get the following error:

The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication.

This is on the data connection of Visual Studio- nothing to do with any code.

How do I make the domain trusted (without login via AD on my machine) or get around this issue?

I tried using Control Panel credential manager but with no luck.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

That is a setting on the domain controller, not on your computer. The domain the SQL Server is in needs to trust the domain you are login in from. As you have a workgroup computer, that domain would be just your computer.

Talk to your domain admin to see if they can make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by running the following command from the same folder as the software:

```
 runas /netonly /user:<Username and Domain> <name of exe>
```